# Percentage of marks in various mark ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql, percentage

I have a table which looks like this

[image]

For each assessment code I would like to create a query which returns the percentage of marks in certain mark ranges... For example

```
 FileYear   AssessmentCode   MarkRange   MarkPercentage

   2014        11cpssdd        0-10           5.88
   2014        11cpssdd        11-20          0
   2014        11cpssdd        21-30          0
   2014        11cpssdd        31-40          0
   2014        11cpssdd        41-50          0
   2014        11cpssdd        51-60          0
   2014        11cpssdd        61-70          0
   2014        11cpssdd        71-80          29.4
   2014        11cpssdd        81-90          52.9
   2014        11cpssdd        91-100         11.7
```

Not sure how to do this at all and was wondering if anyone was able to help? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this calculating the `SUM` of each range and then the percentage of this `SUM` from the whole `SUM`. This is full working example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
    (
         [FileYear] CHAR(4)
        ,[AssessmentCode] CHAR(8)
        ,[StudentID] INT
        ,[Mark] TINYINT
    )   

    INSERT INTO @DataSource ([FileYear], [AssessmentCode], [StudentID], [Mark])
    VALUES ('2014', '11cpssdd', '34323', '75')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '74666', '38')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '87664', '34')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '87576', '66')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '23455', '87')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '87654', '75')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '98776', '75')
          ,('2014', '11cpssdd', '34543', '55')
          ,('2014', '11ecoeco', '87687', '89')
          ,('2014', '11ecoeco', '56466', '77')
          ,('2014', '11ecoeco', '34544', '45')
          ,('2014', '11ecoeco', '95554', '23')
          ,('2014', '11ecoeco', '22322', '56')
          ,('2014', '11ecoeco', '76557', '66')

    SELECT [FileYear]
          ,[AssessmentCode]
          ,[MarkPercentage]
          ,[MarkRange] * 100 /[ALL] AS [MarkRange]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [FileYear]
              ,[AssessmentCode]
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 0 AND 10, [Mark], 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 11 AND 20, [Mark], 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 21 AND 30, [Mark], 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 31 AND 40, [Mark], 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 41 AND 50, [Mark], 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 51 AND 60, [Mark], 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 61 AND 70, [Mark], 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 71 AND 80, [Mark], 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 81 AND 90, [Mark], 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 91 AND 100, [Mark], 0)) 
              ,SUM([Mark])
        FROM @DataSource
        GROUP BY [FileYear]
                ,[AssessmentCode]
    ) DataSource ([FileYear], [AssessmentCode], [0-10], [11-20], [21-30], [31-40], [41-50], [51-60], [61-70], [71-80], [81-90], [91-100], [ALL])
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [MarkRange] FOR [MarkPercentage] IN ([0-10], [11-20], [21-30], [31-40], [41-50], [51-60], [61-70], [71-80], [81-90], [91-100])
    )PVT
    ORDER BY [FileYear]
            ,[AssessmentCode]
            ,[MarkPercentage]

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

[image]

---

Check this solution. Pay attention that we are filtering for specific `AssesmentCode`. Also, if you need the result in `decimal` format, just cast the `[MarkRange]` before division.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
    (
         [FileYear] CHAR(4)
        ,[AssessmentCode] CHAR(8)
        ,[StudentID] INT
        ,[Mark] TINYINT
    )   

    INSERT INTO @DataSource ([FileYear], [AssessmentCode], [StudentID], [Mark])
    VALUES ('2014', '11CPSSDD', '34323', '93')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '74666', '93')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '87664', '90')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '87576', '90')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '23455', '89')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '87654', '86')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '98776', '84')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '34543', '84')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '87687', '84')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '56466', '83')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '34544', '82')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '95554', '80')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '22322', '79')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '76557', '78')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '76557', '77')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '76557', '76')
          ,('2014', '11CPSSDD', '76557', '70')

    SELECT [FileYear]
          ,[AssessmentCode]
          ,[MarkPercentage]
          ,[MarkRange] * 100 /[ALL] AS [MarkRange]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [FileYear]
              ,[AssessmentCode]
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 0 AND 10, 1, 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 11 AND 20, 1, 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 21 AND 30, 1, 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 31 AND 40, 1, 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 41 AND 50, 1, 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 51 AND 60, 1, 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 61 AND 70, 1, 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 71 AND 80, 1, 0)) 
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 81 AND 90, 1, 0))
              ,SUM(IIF([Mark] BETWEEN 91 AND 100, 1, 0)) 
              ,COUNT([Mark])
        FROM @DataSource
        WHERE [AssessmentCode] = '11CPSSDD'
        GROUP BY [FileYear]
                ,[AssessmentCode]
    ) DataSource ([FileYear], [AssessmentCode], [0-10], [11-20], [21-30], [31-40], [41-50], [51-60], [61-70], [71-80], [81-90], [91-100], [ALL])
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [MarkRange] FOR [MarkPercentage] IN ([0-10], [11-20], [21-30], [31-40], [41-50], [51-60], [61-70], [71-80], [81-90], [91-100])
    )PVT
    ORDER BY [FileYear]
            ,[AssessmentCode]
            ,[MarkPercentage]

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: gotqn - thanks so much for your quick response. This is close to what I want it to do. Note that I have changed my initial question above - I have added actual data from my table. When I run your SQL, it shows no one is in the 0 to 10 mark range but it should show 5.88% (1 out of 17). Also the other % are a bit out. There are 9 students in the 81-90 range (52.9%) but I get a figure of 57%. I need the percentage of students in each mark range, not the % of marks in comparison to total marks in each mark range. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: @Barrelnc Check the update solution. I have misunderstood the idea.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly. Thanks again for all your work. I cast the result into decimal format and it is exactly what I need. Still trying to get my head around how it actually works - love the unpivot! Very clever solution - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE Statement to handle conditionally selecting what you need. You will need one for MarkRange column and one to return the MarkPercentage.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This not the exact answer but this should help you i am not sure how u got that percentage. so i have commented that part u can tweak a bit bit get the percentage.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     FileYear       INT,
     AssessmentCode VARCHAR(50),
     StudentID      INT,
     Mark           INT
  )

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES      ( 2014,'11cpssdd',34323,75),( 2014,'11cpssdd',74666,38 ),
            ( 2014,'11cpssdd',87664,34),( 2014,'11cpssdd',87576,66),
            ( 2014,'11cpssdd',23455,87),( 2014,'11cpssdd',87654,75),
            ( 2014,'11cpssdd',98776,75),( 2014,'11cpssdd',34543,55),
            ( 2014,'11ecoeco',87687,89),( 2014,'11ecoeco',56466,77),
            ( 2014,'11ecoeco',34544,45),( 2014,'11ecoeco',95554,23),
            ( 2014,'11ecoeco',22322,56),( 2014,'11ecoeco',76557,66) 

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT 0  AS fst,
                         10 AS scd,
                         fileyear,
                         AssessmentCode
         FROM   #test
         WHERE  AssessmentCode = '11cpssdd'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT scd + 1 fst,
                scd + 10,
                fileyear,
                AssessmentCode
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  scd < 100)
SELECT b.FileYear,
       b.AssessmentCode,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fst) + ' - '
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), scd) MarkRange,
       count(case when mark IS not null then 1 end) Range_Count
       --(count(case when mark IS not null then 1 end)/10.0)*100 percentage
FROM   cte b
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT CASE
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0 - 10'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11 - 20'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21 - 30'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '51 - 60'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN '61 - 70'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN '71 - 80'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN '81 - 90'
                          WHEN mark BETWEEN 90 AND 100 THEN '90 - 100'
                        END [range],
                        FileYear,
                        mark,
                        AssessmentCode
                 FROM   #test
                 WHERE  AssessmentCode = '11cpssdd') a
              ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fst) + ' - '
                 + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), scd) = [range]
                 AND a.AssessmentCode = b.AssessmentCode
GROUP  BY b.FileYear,
          b.AssessmentCode,
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.fst) + ' - '
          + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.scd)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare 10 variable each one for specific range.
2. Use cursor on 'MARK' and increase the relative variable by 1.
3. Do the math. variable=variable/17.
4. Update the variables respectively into new column 'MARK RANGE'.
5. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get your result.

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT FileYear, AssessmentCode, MarkCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM #1
    GROUP BY FileYear, AssessmentCode
)
, b AS
(
    SELECT FileYear, AssessmentCode, Tenth = (Mark - 1)/10 + 1, MarkCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM #1
    GROUP BY FileYear, AssessmentCode, (Mark - 1)/10 + 1
)
SELECT a.FileYear, a.AssessmentCode
, MarkPercentage = CONVERT(varchar(3), Tenth * 10 - IIF(Tenth=1,10,9)) + '-'
                   + CONVERT(varchar(3), Tenth * 10)
, MarkRange = CONVERT(float, LEFT(100.0 * b.MarkCount / a.MarkCount, 4))
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.FileYear = b.FileYear AND a.AssessmentCode = b.AssessmentCode
ORDER BY a.FileYear, a.AssessmentCode
```